# Would a previously poled piezoelectric material experience a force aligning it with an external electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, piezoelectric

I'm wondering if it would possible to crush a poled PZT object, disperse the powder into a thermoplastic (with a melt temperature below the Curie temperature of PZT) and align the 'crystal shards' while still mobile in the plastics liquid phase using an electric field?

The goal of this process would be to make a flexible piece that would undergo deformation via the reverse piezoelectric effect - I realize there are piezoelectric polymers such as PVDF however its piezoelectric modulus values are around two orders of magnitude weaker than for PZT.

Comment: Theoretically yes, and a cursory search shows that this is being worked on, but the results seem to be limited, so far. The best flexible systems seem to be based on thin films. The latter has the advantage over bulk materials that the necessary electric fields can be achieved with much lower voltage. Even if you could make mm or centimeter thick flexible materials, the working voltages would be in the thousands to tens of thousands of V... which is very hard to do for most applications.

Comment: Thanks CuriousOne, could you point me in the direction of the research where its being worked on? The geometry I have in mind is for a fibre/tube so the working thickness would be in the 1 mm ball park.

Comment: There are several commercial manufacturers of think films, as far as I can tell. Since I found links to papers about flexible piezoelectric materials with a simple Google search, I am sure you can, too.

Comment: Sorry, your first comment seemed to imply someone was working on the method I described - for me to stumble on that particular research is a needle in a haystack if I don't know what you used to search google?

Comment: I used "flexible piezoelectric material" and followed a few links. Since I am only here to answer conceptual physics questions, I am usually not willing to do literature searches in addition.

Comment: so you can or cannot for a fact state there is a research project you have read about using the method I outlined? But you don't wish to share that reference because I'm to lazy to read an open ended number of google search results instead of asking you directly?

Comment: I can state for a fact that I just read a textbook excerpt mentioning these materials. My point is entirely that you are expected to do your own research on this site. I can not say anything about how lazy you are about it, but you are surely not giving me a positive impression, right now. I didn't look beyond the second page of my search, by the way... but at least I did look.

Comment: Well I have now checked all the links in the first two pages of the Google search "flexible piezoelectric material" and none of which relate to what I described, I would like to call BS! Please refrain from misrepresenting speculation as fact in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33766/discussion-between-curiousone-and-user263399).